# linq return list where Contains items found

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

using linq: I have an object list of services

```
services[0]
id=1, name="rental", ...

services[1]
id=2. name="buy", ...

services[2]
id=3. name="both", ...
```

..etc

I have array[] contains what services to retrieve from the list selected[]=1,3

```
 foreach(var service in services.where(x=>x.id.Contains(selected))
```

this is where I am stuck how do I add contains into where clause?

build error: contains operator not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) on your array as opposed to the `id`.

```
foreach(var service in services.where(x => selected.Contains(x.id))
```